# Gimp does not display bold, italic, underline, strikethrough icons in the Text Tool

Tags: 18.04, icons, gimp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Gimp 2.10.0. My screen resolution is 2560x1440 (16:9).

As it is seen in the following image - Text Tool does not display the icons of bold, italic, underline, strikethrough. All four are displayed as tiny vertical bars.

[image]

How can I solve this display problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing the snap package and installing the latest Gimp from the `otto-kesselgulasch/gimp` PPA. What I did is as follows.

At first, I removed the previously installed snap package by the following command.

```
sudo snap remove gimp
```

Then I added the latest Gimp from the `otto-kesselgulasch/gimp` PPA using the following set of ommand.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp
```